# Why the below SQL query included results from both tables i.e A and B

Tags: sql

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1 AS A, 2 AS B) A 
JOIN (SELECT 1 AS C, 4 AS D) B ON A.A = B.C
```

Output :-

```
A B C D
1 2 1 4
```

Comment: Because 1=1. What were you expecting?

Comment: What are you trying to find out from your post? Nothing is wrong with it?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That query is not ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: you are selecting all (`*`), if you only want results from a you can use `a.*` or be more specific with `A.A, A.B`

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are selecting "*".
Thats means you want to have everything  from A and B.

If you only want to have Columns from A "OR" B selected, your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM (SELECT 1 AS A, 2 AS B) A JOIN
     (SELECT 1 AS C, 4 AS D) B
      ON A.A = B.C
```

OR

```
SELECT B.*
FROM (SELECT 1 AS A, 2 AS B) A JOIN
 (SELECT 1 AS C, 4 AS D) B
  ON A.A = B.C
```